# Use of ' to indicate missing letters/text

Tags: meaning-in-context, apostrophe, contractions, ellipses

You can write

> this ol' man 'ere

when you mean

> this old man here

But can the ' be used to indicate whole missing sentence parts?

For example:

> 'been a pleasure!

for

> It's been a pleasure!

Comment: I *really* would have loved to answer this question with a single quote character. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apostrophe is used to show a contraction. For example, "don't" is really "do not". However as [Purdue OWL](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/) writes, they are only for the omission of letters within a short phrase. Do not use them for the exclusion of entire words; that is not a function of an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Apostrophe does not let you abbreviate the words - it indicates that the speaker dropped the sound or two while talking. When part of the sentence was omitted, it is not indicated in any way. In your example *Been a pleasure* would be a correct way to write it down.

Comment: "It" has. I don't think that really clears it up any.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no...the apostrophe is generally being used to indicate a missing sound or letter, not an entire word. Strictly speaking:

> Been a pleasure!

Is not grammatically correct, but it would be fine for dialog, and it's perfectly clear what the speaker means. If anything, an apostrophe will only muddy the waters.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends. In representing speech it might well be effective to write:

> 'Spose so.

Comment: Which is *Suppose so*. Apostrophe here does not indicate *I*, but dropping the *u* sound.